# Reuse prepared statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to execute multiple statement in one procedure.

Consider the following case :

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'select * from tbl1';
EXECUTE stmt;

PREPARE stmt FROM 'select * from tbl2';
EXECUTE stmt;

 /* several more executes, around 10 */
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I this valid? Or do I need to deallocate each statement before preparing a new one?
If this is valid would that be recommended or is it better to deallocate each statement, I have no worries about deallocating since I'm nowhere near `max_prepared_stmt_count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found  the answer in the [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/prepare.html)

> If a prepared statement with the given name already exists, it is deallocated implicitly before the new statement is prepared. This means that if the new statement contains an error and cannot be prepared, an error is returned and no statement with the given name exists.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you must deallocate the prepared statement, at least in my short experience with prepared statement i did it and all worked ok for me.